# Java Library To Do Fuzzy Address Matching

Tags: open-source, library, java

I need to implement some matching between 2 sets of addresses.

e.g. Ave. == Avenue etc.

There is a good example of the type of thing on this blog here:

https://www.addy.co.nz/blog/12-tests-for-fuzzy-address-matching

Is there an open-source library that is specific for fuzzy matching addresses?

Comment: perhaps also search for "[address deduplication](https://www.google.com/search?q=address+deduplication)", there is a huge market for these kinds of tools

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Solr or Lucene for that. Solr is very powerful full text search engine made on top of Apache Lucene giving many functionalities. In our project we had create fuzzy search by using solr SearchHandler.

Also we did create our own custom handler for that which used to fetch attributes from the pdf/book which is indexed. Performed Algorithm in that handler and return the results in the form of the list.

You can use [Bitap Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm) for that as well as [Damerau-Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance). They both are used for fuzzy searching.